# Instalación de laravel desde composer

Tags: laravel, composer

Al instalar laravel desde composer con :

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

aparece en línea de comandos

> Using version ^1.3 for laravel/installer
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files

y no instala laravel

Comment: Sale algún error si ejecutas: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` ?

Comment: Hola gracias, siguiendo la documentación de laravel ejecuté ese comando y me funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente, agregué la respuesta para poder cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje que te muestra dice que no actualizó ni instaló nada, puede ser porque ya Laravel está instalado.

Prueba si puedes crear un proyecto ejecutando el comando:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Answer (score 0):

En mis tiempo libre cree un script bajo el lenguaje bash que me permite instalar las herramienta de desarrollo a medida que las llegaba a usar este script se encuentra en el repositorio [scripts-bash](https://github.com/Leo1305Pineda/scripts-bash) la forma de usarlo lo pueden instalar con el comando siguiente:

```
~ $ sudo curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leo1305Pineda/scripts-bash/master/dist/run-tooldev -o /bin/tooldev && sudo chmod a+x /bin/tooldev && tooldev --help
```

Y como todo script dede la terminal de linux lo puedes usar, en tu caso puedes instalar laravel con el comando:

```
~ $ tooldev install laravel
```

Si deseas contribuir te invito a clonar el repositorio o bien si lo que quieres es ver los comando usado para la instalacion de laravel el directorio donde se encuentra instaldo tooldev es el siguiente `/usr/share/tooldev`

Abre con cualquier editor el archivo tooldev.sh, tambien puedes usar `sudo gedit /usr/share/tooldev/tooldev.sh` para editar de forma directa el scripts-bash

usa el comando `~$ tooldev` o `~$ tooldev --help` para ver mas herramientas que puedes instalar.

Si desean comunicar alguna insidencia o problema [Aqui](https://github.com/Leo1305Pineda/scripts-bash/issues) lo podran hacer.